# Interpretation garchFit

Tags: model, garch, arma

```
model_2c=garchFit(~arma(1,1)+garch(1,1), data=logreturn, trace=F, cond.dist='std')
summary(model_2c)   




Error Analysis:
             Estimate  Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)    
    mu      1.750e-04   6.939e-05    2.522  0.01167 *  
    ar1     7.703e-01   8.238e-02    9.351  < 2e-16 ***
    ma1    -8.211e-01   7.316e-02  -11.223  < 2e-16 ***
    omega   9.257e-07   3.372e-07    2.745  0.00605 ** 
    alpha1  8.857e-02   1.199e-02    7.388 1.49e-13 ***
    beta1   9.094e-01   1.134e-02   80.191  < 2e-16 ***
    shape   7.172e+00   1.047e+00    6.851 7.31e-12 ***
```

How do I translate this to the models equations?

$r_t$=1.75*10$^{-4}$+$a_t$+7.703*10$^{-1}$*$a_{t-1}$-8.211*10$^{-1}$*$a_{t-2}$

$sigma^{2}_t$=9.257*10$^{-4}$+8.857*$10^{-2}$*a$^{2}_{t-1}$+9.094*10$^{-1}$*sigma$^2_{t-1}$ 
what am I doing with the "shape" and is above correct? Sorry, I am new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have above is not entirely correct. You err on the AR and MA terms in your model. But the rest looks fine.

You are fitting an ARMA(1,1)-GARCH(1,1) model. The model equations are the following:
$$
\begin{aligned}
(r_t-\mu) &= \varphi_1 (r_{t-1}-\mu) + a_t + \theta_1 a_{t-1}, \\
a_t &= \sigma_t \varepsilon_t, \\
\sigma_t^2 &= \omega + \alpha_1 a_{t-1}^2 + \beta_1 \sigma_{t-1}^2, \\
\varepsilon_t &\sim i.i.d(0,1,\gamma) \\
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\gamma$ is the degrees of freedom parameter of the Student-$t$ distribution. To match this with your estimated model output, $\mu=$`mu`, $\varphi_1=$`ar1`, $\theta_1=$`ma1`, $\omega=$`omega`, $\alpha_1=$`alpha1`, $\beta_1=$`beta1` and $\gamma=$`shape`.

P.S. I am not entirely sure how the constant from the conditional mean model is treated in this package. It could be that the conditional mean equation is 
$$
r_t = \mu + \varphi_1 r_{t-1} + a_t + \theta_1 a_{t-1}.
$$
Probably there is a note on this in the documentation of the "fGarch" package, but I cannot find it as of now.